# Any way to switch SQL Server 2008 Express from "windows autentication" to "mixed mode"?

Tags: windows-7, sql-server-2008

I installed SQL Server Express but may have have done so setting it in "windows authentication" mode.

It took forever to install. Is there a way to switch it to "mixed mode" (or even verify whether it's in Mixed Mode)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this registry hack.  Change the value in:

```
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\Instance Name\MSSQLServer\LoginMode
```

to 0 or 2 for mixed mode.  1 means integrated auth.

Details are in this [MS KB](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/285097).

Comment: I ended up just reinstalling. I think that may have been a better idea because it also prompted me for a Server Admin Password during the install (didn't do that in previous install).

Comment: you can re-set the sa password from your integrated auth login

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to download and install [SQL Server Management Studio Express](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=C243A5AE-4BD1-4E3D-94B8-5A0F62BF7796&displaylang=en) and see/set the authentication mode using it.

Once SSMSE is installed, you can connect to your SQL Server instance, right click the instance name and go to Properties. From there go to the Security page, and you should see a radio selection for "Windows authentication mode" or "SQL Server and Windows authentication mode". The latter is mixed mode.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server Management Studio:

1. Open Object Explorer
2. Right click on root entry
3. Click Properties
4. Under Security Change to: **SQL Server and Windows Authentication Mode**